# .htaccess SSL rule conflicting with www redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am completely unfamiliar with .htaccess and have been looking through forums and trying several examples to try and construct a htaccess rule that will solve our problem.

We have had a rule in place to redirect all traffic to the www. version of our domain name which has worked well.

However now we have bought a secure certificate for the URL without the www. Unfortunately no matter how many rules I put in to overwrite the above rule I can't seem to overwrite it.

Here is our www redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ourwebsite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourwebsite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

We need to allow the following domain `https://ourwebsite.com.au/this-page.html`

Does anyone know how I can allow the following URL without affecting the first rule.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just concerned about not applying that rule when the site is accessed over HTTPS, you can just condition it using the `%{HTTPS}` variable:

```
# Only worry about this rule when HTTPS isn't on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ourwebsite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourwebsite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you decide to apply the www/non-www uniformly for both http/https requests, you can take a look at the examples on the [mod_rewrite tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) which explain how to accomplish this.